# Python - How does appending in a list and changing an element in a list differs in case of shallow copy

Tags: python-3.x, list, append, shallow-copy

Okay, so I had a doubt regarding the difference between the append and change operation in lists with respect to shallow copy.

Below is the output:

```
***After Shallow Copy***
a = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [True, False]]
b = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [True, False]]

***After appending in list a (Here appending in list a doesn't affect list b)***
a = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [True, False], [1, 'a', True]]
b = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [True, False]]

***After appending in list b (Same as above appending in b doesn't affect a)***
a = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [True, False], [1, 'a', True]]
b = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [True, False], [2, 'b', False]]

***After changing 2 to 10 in list a (But changing an element gets reflected in both)***
a = [[1, 10, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [True, False], [1, 'a', True]]
b = [[1, 10, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [True, False], [2, 'b', False]]

***After changing a to z in list b (Same as above changed an element in b and reflected in both)***
a = [[1, 10, 3], ['z', 'b', 'c'], [True, False], [1, 'a', True]]
b = [[1, 10, 3], ['z', 'b', 'c'], [True, False], [2, 'b', False]]
```

Comment: If you keep a reference in your list (a or b) and change the data this reference points to, it changes the underlying data. both refs point to it, so the changes are "reflected". use `id(..)` on variables to see if they got the same id - if so, they are same. Read up on mutables and immutables.

Comment: "Shallow copy" means you didn't copy the elements of `a` to `b`, you merely created another list whose elements refer to the same elements as `a`.

Answer (score 0):

STRAIGHT OUTA Python's DOCUMENTATION:

- > A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the
  >   extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in
  >   the original.
- > A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then,
  >   recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the
  >   original.

For more info, refer here: https://realpython.com/copying-python-objects/

Comment: I am having a doubt about how append and changing an element is different in Shallow copy. As you can see that appending in original list doesn't have any effect in the copied list and vice-versa. But while changing an element in any of the list has an effect on both of them.